# How to apply an object shape image mask to an image via Google Slides API

Tags: google-slides-api

On slides.google.com, after inserting an image, it's possible to "mask image" with shapes.

I don't see anything about doing this programmatically in the API Reference documentation, nor see anything in the "slides.presentations.get" API response that explains how they are specifying to mask the image with a particular shape.

How can image masking be accomplished via the Google Slides API?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for retrieving and setting the image mask in [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview?hl=en) and [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/), yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#replaceallshapeswithimagerequest), the shape mask is ignored when replacing images:

> The images replacing the shapes are rectangular after being inserted
> into the presentation and do not take on the forms of the shapes.